# Saving form settings on exit

Tags: c#

I am trying to have my application save some form settings on exit.

Eg. I have a textbox and a checkbox and I want to save the states of both to a settings file.

I already know how to save the settings to the settings file, the trouble is that the settings don't save in the exiting method.

My application exit method is this:

```
void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exiting...");
    session.Default.Path = txtPath.Text;
    session.Default.Regex = chkRegex.Checked;
}
```

These are the two ways I've tried to have it call on exit:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnApplicationExit);
}
```

And

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormClosing += OnApplicationExit;
}
```

With both, the method gets called, the message box is shown but neither save the settings. I think the form controls are getting unloaded before it has a chance to read the values.

How can I save these form control values on exit?

Comment: what is `session` here?

Comment: If this is Windows Forms, there's a Form Closing event.  That's where I write my user settings off to a file.  I usually write an XML file off to Isolated Storage (so that the user can't easily find and delete it)

Comment: session is the name of the settings file, I called it session as it contains previous session data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what i think it is, then this might be relevant

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp)

> Settings that are application-scoped are read-only, and can only be
>   changed at design time or by altering the .config file in between
>   application sessions. Settings that are user-scoped, however, can be
>   written at run time just as you would change any property value. The
>   new value persists for the duration of the application session. You
>   can persist the changes to the settings between application sessions
>   by calling the Save method.

So likely, you could just call

```
session.Default.Save();
```

<sub>***Note*** : I could be completely wrong</sub>

Comment: I'll take another look. I do have another form which saves the settings fine, however I may be mistaken and it may revert after I restart my application. I will look again tonight. Thanks.